# Read data from Dictionary

Tags: c#, json

I am facing a problem for parsing a JSON array in C#

```
{
    "details" : [{
            "state" : "myState1",
            "place" : [{
                    "name" : "placeName",
                    "age" : 13
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "state" : "myState2",
            "place" : [{
                    "name1" : "placeName"
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "state" : "myState3",
            "place" : [{
                    "name2" : "placeName"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

My code is:

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{ 
    string txt = File.ReadAllText("MyJSONFile.txt"); 
    JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer(); 
    var data = ser.Deserialize(txt); 
}

public class Wrap
{ 
    public List<Dictionary<string, object>> details { get; set; } 
}
```

How can I read data from these dictionaries? Sometimes the JSON will include only 1 facility's details, but other times there are more than 30 items in the array. This data is being pulled from the database.

Comment: public class Wrap
    {
        public List<Dictionary<string, object>> details { get; set; }
    }

Comment: check this [link](http://www.drowningintechnicaldebt.com/ShawnWeisfeld/archive/2010/08/22/using-c-4.0-and-dynamic-to-parse-json.aspx) or this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object/3806407#3806407)

Comment: I will suggest you to use [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) and for generating the required classes you can use [Json2CSharp](http://json2csharp.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following C# classes structure:

```
public class Place
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
    public string name1 { get; set; }
    public string name2 { get; set; }
}

public class Detail
{
    public string state { get; set; }
    public List<Place> place { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public List<Detail> details { get; set; }
}

public class Program 
{
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    { 
        string txt = File.ReadAllText("MyJSONFile.txt"); 
        JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer(); 
        var data = ser.Deserialize<Root>(txt); 

        Console.WriteLine(data.details.Count); // 3
        Console.WriteLine(data.details[0].state); // myState1
        Console.WriteLine(data.details[1].place.Count); // 1
        Console.WriteLine(data.details[1].place[0].age); // 13
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The class structure you are using is wrong. 
You will have to use the structure as follows, which corresponds to your JSON. 
This structure have been generated using [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/)

```
public class Place
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
    public string name1 { get; set; }
    public string name2 { get; set; }
}

public class Detail
{
    public string state { get; set; }
    public List<Place> place { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Detail> details { get; set; }
}
```

Now in your code you can de serialize this using Newtonsoft.Json as follows:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     string jsonText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("MyJSONFile.txt");
     var rootObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonText);
     rootObj.details.ForEach(detail =>
     {
         Console.WriteLine(detail.state);
         detail.place.ForEach(p =>
         {
             if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p.name) == false)
             {
                  Console.WriteLine(p.name);
             }
             if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p.name1) == false)
             {
                  Console.WriteLine(p.name1);
             }
             if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p.name2) == false)
             {
                  Console.WriteLine(p.name2);
             }
             if (p.age > 0)
             {
                  Console.WriteLine(p.age);
             }
             Console.WriteLine(string.Empty);
         });
     });
     Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```